# How to deploy C# console application?

Tags: c#

as stated in the title. I have tried copying the entire bin\debug folder but the application doesnt run on other computers. I believe the console application will not run if the host PC does not have visual studio and tools installed. Is there a way to deploy the application such that it can run on any computer?

Edit: sorry for not including more details.
I first started with having a missing assembly `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` but i have managed to fixed that but getting the dll from nuget. The host PC im testing on has the required .NET 4.5.2 installed, and the current error message i have is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplicat‌​ion.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: I believe the console application will not run if the host PC does not have visual studio and tools installed. - Wrong

Comment: It would require the .net framework and other related dll's to be present on the machine. why dont you write a error logger or a simple console.write and see what the error might be?? for a fair start you need to have the .net framework in the machine

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't run on other computers"? Is there something in the event viewer? Does it throw an exception? Do you have it compiled for "AnyCPU" or "x86"? What error do you get?  Deploy it with Debug build first and capture the errors and include that in your error message. Also include the version of .NET, and whether the target computer has .NET installed.  Without this information we can't solve the problem.

Comment: Dont downvote... .. I still think this is a valid question for a beginner.

Comment: sorry for the insufficient information. i have updated the post.

Comment: Since you say it's a "console application" are you just running an .exe or are you planning on installing with an .msi that is built with InstallShield (or the like)? If the latter, you can package the needed .NET libraries with the install-able and they will be installed in the package if the target computer needs them.

Comment: So you have `WebApplications` referenced in the assembly? why if it's a console application?

Comment: i didnt use any web application API, no idea why its there and i did not have it referenced in my project either. @bradykey im planning to just run it in a console. just the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Please open your project file. Please comment the below code if it can be found to see if it works.

`<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>`

Comment: cant find that in my project file.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code? so I can check and post with the updated code.

In my local, i am able to publish to Azure as a webjod and able to publish in local and install/run the application.